# Use custom HTTP client with Google's API go library?

Tags: go, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4, google-api-go-client

In order to make use of Google's API `go` SDK, we need to make use of the [token source](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.60.0/option#WithTokenSource). This works great on its own, but becomes a problem when using [a custom HTTP client](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/api@v0.60.0/option#WithHTTPClient).

The documentation does mention that options are not preserved when making use of a custom HTTP client. This is necessary for us in order to instrument our client.

Is there a way to make use of an HTTP client and a token source at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `WithHTTPClient` rules out the use of any other option, the alternative is to prepare the http client with the token source. To achieve that, the transport needs to be defined.

```
service, err := ggoauth2.NewService(
    ctx,
    option.WithHTTPClient(&http.Client{
        Timeout: 30 * time.Second,
        Transport: &oauth2.Transport{
            Base:   http.DefaultTransport,
            Source: tokenSource,
        },
    }),
)
```